# Timer Tick или как настроить таймер?

Tags: c#

Помогите разобраться с таймером. Нужно чтобы он показывал минуты и секунды, а так же обратный отсчет.

У меня не получается добавить минуты. Время тупо идет и все. Типа поле 00:60, должна появиться первая минута, а секунды идти с начала (01:00), но у меня просто продолжаются идти секунды (60, 61, 62 и т.д.), как это можно исправить?

```
public int sec, min;
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (sec == 60)
        {
            sec = 60;
            min += 1;
        }
        if (min == 60)
            min = 1;
    }
private void progressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBlock1.Text = ProgressPos.Value.ToString();
        textBlock2.Text = ProgressPos.Value.ToString(":"+min + "" + sec);
    }
```

Comment: `if (sec == 60) sec = 60;` а это зачем?

Comment: Покажите код где вы запускаете таймер

Comment: `timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = new TimeSpan() };
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не храните отдельно минуты и секунды. У Вас есть значение секунд? Получите из него `TimeSpan`и выводите его в нужном формате:

```
var time=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sec).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Блин, чет не знаю. Я что-то сделал, но это не правильно, хрень какая-то. Тупа опять секунды идут и все (ну видимо потому что хрень написал). 
    `private void progressBar_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
            textBlock1.Text = ProgressPos.Value.ToString(+time+"");    
        }`

Comment: `ProgressPos.Value` - это что? Почему берется `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)`?

Comment: `ProgressPos` это x:Name у ProgressBar'a (в XAML назначил). `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)` это чтобы отсчет начинался с 0-вой секунды (ну это я вчера в интене нашел)

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0).ToString()` выдаст `"00:00:00"`. Вы эту строку используете в качестве формата для своих секунд. Т.е. 132-я секунда выдастся как `00:01:32`, потому что Вы не формируете время из секунд, а по прежнему выводите число этих секунд. Напишите просто: `textBlock1.Text=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ProgressPos.Value,"HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: ну если написать так, как вы сказали `textBlock1.Text=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ProgressPos.Value,"HH:mm:ss");`, то у меня ошибку выдает, что  `Ни одна из перегрузок метода "FromSeconds" не принимает 2 аргументов.`
ArgumentException и OverflowException

Comment: Да, ошибся: `textBlock1.Text=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ProgressPos.Value).ToString()`

Comment: спасибо, работает, только вот там отображение очень точно)) как убрать миллисекунды? `ToString("HH:mm:ss")`   не работает. Хотя мне очень интересно, почему не работает, т.к. ошибку не выдает, а просто закрывает приложение.

Comment: Хотя я в XAML блок подогнал))

Comment: нашел
`ToString("mm\\:ss")`